# How to handle CNAME records pointing to my server

Tags: codeigniter, server, dns, cpanel, cname

I am creating a application where people can create custom domain and link their domain to my serer through CNAME record. please have a link on below application, this is something similar i am creating.

https://codecanyon.net/item/belink-ultimate-url-shortener/24354590?s_rank=1

I have created a CNAME record on name.wproutes.com and pointed to target.dblcto.co
https://www.whatsmydns.net/#CNAME/name.wproutes.com
Now if i click on https://name.wproutes.com it should redirect to target.dblcto.co but its redirecting somewhere else.

Now my concern is how can i handle on htaccess or in routes so whenever someone use their custom domain and point to my domain target.dblcto.co , it will redirect to target.dblcto.co and i can write some code here.

I really appreciate your help Thanks.

Comment: Your DNS configuration may be conflicting with itself. There's an A record for `name.wproutes.com` pointing to an IP address. If you want to redirect a subdomain using a `CNAME` record, there shouldn't be an A record pointing that same subdomain to an IP address (IIRC, A records will always take precedence over CNAME records)

Comment: i have added only CNAME not A record..

Comment: If you check https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/name.wproutes.com you'll see there IS an A record for `name.wproutes.com`